# Video/audio desyncing on TV or monitor with Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

It's exactly what's on the title. Would anyone know an answer for this?

If it helps, I'm on build 1809 (LTSC 2019), but any ideas for other builds can be given too. I'll try them all. By the way, I've reinstalled the system with Keep Everything option already (not because of this, but I did), and it's still the same issue.

It happens with VLC, Windows Media Player and BS Player, at least. I didn't try more. Though, I don't think it happens playing videos on Edge (the browser I use). At least I don't notice. On VLC I'm 1000000% positive of it, first because I can notice perfectly from 15 to 15 minutes, and then because I need to go on the computer and click Pause and then Play again for it to get back to normal (amazing when watching movies...). After Pause and then Play, the sound stops for maybe half a second and then plays again, like if it was waiting for the video to come to place and then continues normal playback. Until it does it again...

Any ideas about this? When I had Windows 7 on this thing months ago I could watch movies on a TV or monitor or whatever. Now I can't...... Any help is appreciated!

**PS:** I can do any testing required to understand the problem better, just say. I've a TV and a PC monitor, so I can test things on both if needed too.

**UPDATE:** I had never tried, but while I did other things, I left my computer playing a movie on my external monitor. Neither with Only External Monitor, nor with Expanded modes there was any problem. On the TV, on both modes, the issue will always happen.

Also, doesn't matter if it's on battery or plugged in. It will happen anyways.

**UPDATE 2:** Also happens with my external monitor after all (yesterday watched a movie and had to be pausing/playing - breaking Star Wars movies like this must be a sin hahaha). Assume to always happen on any device connected to the HDMI port, so it's less specific.

**UDPATE 3:** Just tried formatting and installing build 1809 from scratch. Only installed the GPU driver. No updates at all or other programs (writing this from Internet Explorer). Problem remains. Either GPU driver(?) problem (weird?), or Windows 10 problem. At minimum from build 1809. I'll try and see what happens with 1607.

**UPDATE 4:** **Problem seems to be on build 1809 and some others.** From what a person told me, it used to happen with him on 1803, and I read someone saying it happened on 1909 too. So might be Windows problem on those builds (at least). Seems not to be that rare to have this problem, from what I Googled around after realizing the problem might be in Windows. Was suggested on sites it could be drivers. I had not Realtek Audio drivers installed. Only Nvidia, to connect to the TV through the HDMI port. Same version on 1809 and 1607, same test file, same VLC version, no Internet. Problem on 1809 and not on 1607 --> ????? How can a system break audio/video synchronization!?

Answer (score 0):

most TVs come set up with settings which introduce latency: noise reduction, white point balance, variable darkness or gamma based on scene brightness. The easiest way to test to see if this is *the* issue is to either turn all of these things off or look to see if there is a "game mode" setting on the tv

Comment: Thanks. I'll try when I get back home. Though, Why would that happen only after upgrading to Windows 10? Wouldn't then that be a problem on the TV? Because before Windows 10 this didn't happen. I'd watch movies on TVs with this computer and everything would work perfectly. Also works on other computers. Only it doesn't on this one, now with Windows 10.

Comment: Took infinity, but checked it. Doesn't seem to be that. Nor there neither in the PC monitor that option exists. Would love to know what the problem is here.... And I can't test on Oracle VM Box also because the movie won't show video on VLC (no graphics card to play 1080p maybe). Any other ideas are appreciated.